# AdColony - HeyZap - Swift - Ad not showing

Tags: swift, adcolony

[image]

[image]

I have integrated Heyzap framework in my app and also configured all the ad network in Heyzap site successfully.

My problem is that i'm fetching and showing ads in AdColony. But Only Interstitial ad are fetched and not showing any ads. Just black screen is showing for 2 seconds and then it's over.

Note - I have configured Test Ad to YES in app configuration perfectly.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: AdColony appears to be properly configured in the Heyzap backend, but no video ads show, neither in the above test view nor in our game. All other video providers fetch and display video ads as intended.

Comment: do you have plugged in headphone to your machine. If you are playing with simulator there is audio out put is required.

Comment: I'm testing on iPhone 5, no headphones

Comment: Then it's fine. Whatever but as per my client requirements I have to integrate Heyzap. And my personal experience for Heyzap is very bad. As per functionality not working properly. And i am communicating from last 8 days for issues and they are releasing new version everyday. And i'm giving issues to them and they are solve one issue and raise another. And next day i'm informing them to new one. After end of day they release new version :). I have started with 8.3.0 and now it's 9.0.3 version. Finally i have decided to give feedback to Heyzap team every day. Bcoz they providing good mediation.